# Dynamically Pass Data into Flot Chart with PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic, flot

I have been using Flot charts to try and display some data on my webpage. Works perfectly with static data but I want to pull this data dynamically from my database. But I am struggling with a few aspects of this,

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php while($test = sqlsrv_fetch_array($testData, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <p><i class="fa fa-square blue"></i><?php echo $test['SalesGroup'];?> </p>
       </td>
       <td>
         <?php echo $test['PercentageSales'];?>
       </td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Which is prinitng out the legend fine, my query here is can i change the colour class in this case 'blue' for each row of data?

Then in my JavaScript,this is where I am really struggling,  how can i make this data dynamic? I am wanting to set the category names to match the PHP legend above. The datasets need to be the 'PercentageSales' from the legend. Also the colours if possible because their isn't always going to be 6 results.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var options = {
      legend: false,
      responsive: false
    };

    new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas1"), {
      type: 'doughnut',
      tooltipFillColor: "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.55)",
      data: {
        labels: [
          "Category 1",
          "Category 2",
          "Category 3",
          "Category 4",
          "Category 5",
          "Category 6",
        ],
        datasets: [{
          data: [16.6,16.6,16.6,16.6,16.6,16.6],
          backgroundColor: [
            "#BDC3C7",
            "#9B59B6",
            "#E74C3C",
            "#26B99A",
            "#3498DB",
            "#34495E"
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#CFD4D8",
            "#B370CF",
            "#E95E4F",
            "#36CAAB",
            "#49A9EA",
            "#34495E"
          ]
        }]
      },
      options: options
    });
  });
</script>
```

I appreciate this a large question but help in any direction will be massive.

Comment: Is it that, what you are searching for? [http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/]

Comment: Unfortunately the link you provided doesn't seem to give much data about how implement what I need, if you could elaborate that would be much appreciated.